# Is an online chi square calculator available for larger tables?

Tags: chi-squared-test, internet

I am looking for an online Chi square calculator. I can see there are many for 2x2 tables. I am looking for an online calculator which can accommodate dimensions beyond 2x2.

Comment: Do you really need to do it using web application?

Comment: web or desktop version that can run on windows. in case I had not understoood your question, I am new to statistics and such a calculator will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this? http://faculty.vassar.edu/lowry/newcs.html

Comment: thanks for the inputs. Pls correct me if wrong, How do I change the DF in that calculator?

Comment: The df, I guess, is determined by the size of the table. Just prepare table of size you need

Comment: Found another one as well perhaps could be useful http://quantpsy.org/chisq/chisq.htm

Answer (score 1):

Slightly old thread, but one can use the [OpenEpi](http://www.openepi.com) website as well, under the `R by C table` option, and one can input quite complex tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another on line tool: 
http://www.physics.csbsju.edu/stats/contingency_NROW_NCOLUMN_form.html

Answer (score 0):

This Chi-square calculator can fit ANY size tables: https://www.icalcu.com/stat/chisqtest.html
The easiest way is to copy/paste all the numbers (excluding row header and columns headers) within an EXCEL table directly into the link, click "Calculate", and and the summary will appear below it.