# I need a calculator that uses a contigency table of 11x6

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, internet

I need a calculator that uses a contigency table of 11x6. Anyone knows where I can find a calculator for my case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51871/3277) answer should suit you best, I think. I vote to close your question as duplicate.